# Conditionally connect to a database

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

To access a database one has to specify the DB details in the conf file.

If the DB is up everything works fine.

If the DB is down Play throws an exception, which I cannot control.

I would like to conditionally connect to a DB. Lets say I only want to connect to a DB if a flag is set somewhere. Is there a more manual way to connect to a DB in Play?

Update:
I guess I haven't been very clear.

I want the App to not fail if the DB is down and fetch data from other alternate sources. How can I accomplish this in PLAY?

Comment: What do you mean by more manual way? If you want, you can always fallback on Jdbc or whatever database API you want.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to start your app without a DB for development? You can pass an alternative config file on startup where you for example configure a in memory db:

```
start -Dconfig.resource=development.conf
```

edit:

You can configure several databases in your app config and get them with `DB.getDataSource(name: String)` or get a connection to it with `DB.getConnection(name: String)` or even run a transaction with DB.getConnection[A](name: String)(f: Connection => A)

see: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.db.DB$

Comment: What I want is for Play to fallback to an alternate source of data(a cache for example) when the DB connection fails.

Comment: I don't think that this is a very common use case. The other way around is no problem: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaCache

You should rather make your database highly available.

Comment: So Play provides very little control over the DB connection?

Comment: I didn't say that, did I? You can basically do whatever you like with your DB: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaDatabaseOthers